# IsMouserOver Interference With IsSelected in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Hey guys I have an issue with triggers for `IsMouserOver` and `IsSelected`.
My goal is to create an animation that changes the `BorderThickness` of my `ListViewItems` in `IsMouserOver`. Using `EnterActions` and `ExitActions` yields the desired result, however, when I try to also take into account the `IsSelected` property in another trigger, every property but `BorderThickness` can be set.

When I remove the whole `IsMouseOver` trigger, `BorderThickness` will be set in `IsSelected` and displayed correctly.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" x:Key="SubMenuStyles">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">                    
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"/>               
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimation 
   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" From="0,0,0,0" To="10,0,0,0" 
    Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimation 
  Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" From="10,0,0,0"  To="0,0,0,0" 
                     Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>

        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ListViewItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#233E4F"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="50,0,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"/>
        </Trigger>          
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I edited your post as it was very difficult to understand your problem and goal due to (lack of) punctuation etc. I hope I did not change the meaning.

Comment: But when you make your IsMouseOver it changed the Thickness or not?. I mean when you just move the mouse without selected the item.

Comment: No the IsMouserOver Works Perfectly Fine But when I select The Listviewitem it Doesn't Add The BorderThickness that i Defined In it

Comment: I just wanna Know Why when I select The ListViewItem The BorderThickness That i Defined In The Trigger Of IsSelected Doesn't Work And why is it when i Remove the whole Trigger For The IsMouseOver Then The Borderthickness Inside IsSelected Works !

Comment: You need to do multitriggers, because when you change the isMouseover it deletes the border, so you need to make condition if selected item to not remove the border. I can make answer, but @Thomas will be quicker because I belive it is already writting it;)

Comment: @Kaspar I am indeed ;) but that shouldn't stop you from posting your own - I might miss the point, or your answer could be better than mine, so go for it :)

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

The behavior you encountered before is shown in the picture below:

[image]

where the problem is that your orange **border is being reset every time** the mouse is over the selected item.

---

What I believe you want to achieve is to keep the fixed 50px border on a selected item, like shown below:

[image]

---

## Solution

In order to achieve that, we need to find a way to execute the animation only for items that are not selected (i.e. where `IsSelected="False")`.
This is where [`MultiTrigger`](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/multi-triggers-multitrigger-multidatatrigger/)s come into play.

`MultiTrigger`s are quite like "normal" `Trigger`s with the important addition that they fire not when only one condition is fulfilled, but when **all conditions are fulfilled**.

e.g.

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
        <!-- More conditions, if you want -->
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
        <!-- Will only be set when ALL conditions are fulfilled. -->
    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
    <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        <!-- Will also only be executed when ALL conditions are fulfilled -->
    </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
</MultiTrigger>
```

---

## Code

So, in your case, adjust your style to look like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SubMenuStyles" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ListViewItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#233E4F" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="50,0,0,0" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange" />
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange" />
                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness"
                                                From="0,0,0,0"
                                                To="10,0,0,0"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness"
                                                From="10,0,0,0"
                                                To="0,0,0,0"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView Width="200"
              Height="150"
              Margin="30">
        <ListViewItem Style="{StaticResource SubMenuStyles}">A ListView</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem IsSelected="True" Style="{StaticResource SubMenuStyles}">with several</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem Style="{StaticResource SubMenuStyles}">items</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes Thank You very Much My problem was Just When I selected The borderThickness Didin't work and Suprisingly when i Removed the IsMouseOver Triggers Enter and exit actions it works But thanks again

Comment: @Sara glad to hear that it worked. If my answer (or any other yet to come) has helped you, please *mark it as accepted* by ticking the green tick next to the answer.

Comment: ok So I tryed Out Your Code But I still Get The same Results No BorderThickness When The ListView Is Selected You Sure U didin't maked any Changes To The Listview Or ListViewItems On The tags ?

Comment: @Sara you don't need to be sorry :) I edited the answer to include the full code needed to get exactly the same result as shown in the second gif. Please try if

Comment: Wait A sec U Test Out My Code And the Result was the 1st Picture? !!!! srsly This is Getting Awkward Right now I wanted to achive The 1st but The Cod Works For you Perfectly Fine but For me Not ?

Comment: srsly im lossing Confidence In My Pc's Logic  :)

Comment: @Sara exactly... your code yields the first picture.

Comment: [link](https://pasteboard.co/HJLgb7M.png)  This Is The Picture Of the Result's Of Both Urs and My Code Same same Result's

Comment: But It Doesn't For me ! See The Picture Both Yours And Mine Give same Result's No BorderThickness When Selected !

Comment: @Sara, I really would love to help you, but I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve. Do you want to achieve **exactly** what I have shown in the first picture, or what I have shown in the second picture, or something very different altogether? Can you please try to describe what you want to achieve (without worrying about things like `BorderThickness` etc., just like `"when an item is selected and I hover about it, I want it to be orange all the time (or animated)"`)?

Comment: Ok lets Just Say I want To achive the 2st Image that U Gived and The Code that you've showen I tryed It Out And still I can't Make The ListviewItem's BorderThickness to 50 When Selected Thats all the issue I have i Just want To Click The ListViewItem And The BorderThickness Changes Without Removing any IsMouseOver Triggers Thats all But i tryed out Your Code And when I Click At The ListViewItem I still Get No BorderThickneses

Comment: @Sara now I understand... that's a little more complicated, please give me a little more time

Comment: @Sara the animations are super-complicated right now... but in general, is [this](https://pasteboard.co/HJLBm5j.gif) what you want to achieve (with added animation, I will work on that)?

Comment: Yes This One But with Little Bit Modified When U Remove ur MouseOver The BorderThickness Animationay Closes But yea In total

Comment: @Sara alright, I cannot promise anything, but I will try my best to add the animations etc. and edit my answer afterwards.